# In React js, what is the elegant way to add page message after potentially any input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I am having a page message:

```
<div className={alertClass}>
    <i className="fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg"></i> {this.props.message}
</div>
```

I can potentially show this page message before or after any input field in my form, based on which field has caused the issue.

In jQuery, this is easy to achieve via simply append. But how do we achieve this is react? By adding a

```
{this.state.showAlertMessage ? <AlertMessage
    alertClass={this.state.alertClass}
    message={this.state.alertMessage}/> : null}
```

before each input box seem to be achievable but nothing elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant way is to pass in showAlertMessage as a prop to the alert message component and just have the alert component there all the time. Then in the alert message component, the render method uses the message prop in a condition determining whether the object should be displayed. When alert message state is updated on the parent, the components using it are updated as well.